# Google Test include gtest/gtest.h

Tags: c++, unix, include, googletest, fatal-error

I'm getting started with Google Test for C++. Unfortunately I'm having trouble trying to include the header files. The first line of my little test program sumTest.cpp says

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
```

while subTest.cpp is in the same directory as gtest . gtest also contains the directory called internal, which contains gtest-internal.h . When I try to compile subTest.cpp from the terminal, it says

> g++ sumTest.cpp
> In file included from sumTest.cpp:1:
> ./gtest/gtest.h:62:10: fatal error: 'gtest/internal/gtest-internal.h' file not found
> #include "gtest/internal/gtest-internal.h"
> ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> 1 error generated.

So it finds the file gtest/gtest.h but not the file gtest/internal/gtest-internal.h , which seems strange to me.

I'm thankful for every kind of help.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! So do I have to add that path to my list of include search paths?

Comment: It might be worthwhile to familiarize yourself with CMake or at least [install googletest](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/README.md#standalone-cmake-project) properly and configure the include/lib paths for your project.

Answer (score 1):

[The line with your error](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/include/gtest/gtest.h#L62) is the first local include statement in gtest.h. The directory that contains gtest is not in your list of include search paths.

`gtest/gtest.h` is working only because it's relative to the current file.

You need to add the path that contains the directory `gtest` to your list of include search paths.

Comment: On Windows, when gtest is included using nuget, no include path configuration is needed, it seems.  Do you have information on how this is achieved? Thank you.